How do I get Jupyter Notebook to work with Python 3.10 installed on my PC?
The situation: I need to use Python 3.10 specifically for some project. (instructions below) With it, I have to run a file with jupyter notebook. However, after downloading python 3.10, I cannot seem to open/download. The issue cannot be that big, any ideas?
instructions: First, create a virtual environment using Python 3.10:
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv nameofthevenv --python python3.10
source nameofthevenv/bin/activate
Then, inside the virtualenv:

(nameofthevenv) $ pip install jupyter ipykernel
(nameofthevenv) $ python -m ipykernel install --user --name nameofthevenv
(nameofthevenv) $ jupyter notebook

and here's my current error message:
after installing, i used virtualenv nameofthevenv --python python3.10
but got
'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

when that's not supposed to be. I'm thinking its "an issue with PATH" according to a friend, but i'm a total noob and don't know what that is.

So it looks like you ran pip install virtualenv and then tried virtualenv nameofthevenv --python python3.10 but see that message'virtualenv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, ..., is that right? Did you see any notes when you ran the first pip install command? It looked like it ran fine? There are a lot of cautions agains using pip install for this here in the documentation. Did you then shift to trying python -m pip install --user virtualenv like the documentation advises?

yeah I did that too, I got this  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\McNair Scholars Prog\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed distlib-0.3.8 virtualenv-20.26.3 I don't know what the warning means, how I get past this?

It means that location isn't registered in the places your system looks for code to run. You need to add it to your system's path. If you aren't following how to use a virtualenv on your machine. installing the Anaconda Distribution may be easier? If you do that, follow the Getting Started info on how to make an environment for this project. That way your base will be the standard that comes with Anaconda Distribution now and you won't mess anything up.
